# What the heck is a memory channel "CS bus"?

Tags: computer-architecture, memory-hardware

While I was reading about memory architecture from [the CMSC 22200's Lecture 17 of University of Chicago](https://classes.cs.uchicago.edu/archive/2016/fall/22200-1/lecture_notes/li-cmsc22200-aut16-lecture17.pdf), I got stuck on determining the meaning of the word "CS" used for describing a bus as part of memory channel:

[image: Memory Channel architecture brief description]

However I didn't find any additional source pointing out that bus. And furthermore, I found on [different reference](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~rajeev/cs6810/mem.pdf) that:

> The memory channel is made up of a data bus and an address/comm and
>   bus.

So, I don't know from where they got the information about the "CS bus"? And what is it exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is the "Chip Select" part which is mentioned at slide 26.

It probably selects whether to use the chip on the front or in the back.